# MySQL update just day in date column in many rows

Tags: mysql, date

Having this rows:

```
1|2015-04-22
2|2015-03-11
3|2015-02-15
```

I want update on all rows just the day, example:

```
1|2015-04-25
2|2015-03-25
3|2015-02-25
```

Comment: Do you want an `update` or `select`?

Comment: I want Update these rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep the year and month the same, and change all the days to the 25th of whichever year and month are shown.

The formula you need is

```
DATE(DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn, '%Y-%m-25'))
```

So, to update the table it's

```
UPDATE mytable SET datecolumn =  DATE(DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn, '%Y-%m-25'))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date to a string, putting in the 25th:

```
select t.id,
       date(concat_ws('-', year(dte), month(dte), 25))
from table t;
```

Another way would be to subtract the current day of the month, minus 1, and add back 25:

```
select t.id,
       dte + interval (1 - day(dte) + 24) day
from table t;
```

EDIT:

As an update:

```
update table t
    set dte = dte + interval (25 - day(dte)) day;
```